# nested routes react router 4

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

when I click on a user image, the Id is changed in URL ("/r/:id") but page content remains the same.

```
<BrowserRouter>
  <Switch>
      <Route path="/r/:id" component={View} />
  </Switch>
</BrowserRouter>,

<Link
  to={{
    pathname: `/r/${item.uid}`,
    state: item,
  }}
>

  <div className="video-overlay" >
    <div className="imagepop" >
      <div className="box-imag" >
        <img
          alt="#"
          className="img-responsive img-over"
          src={(item.cover) || two}
        />
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</Link>
```

Comment: what's your `View` component?

Comment: It is container

Comment: Can you add it to the question?

Comment: No, I have not added.

Comment: it's hard to help if you don't show your code...

Answer (score 0):

Try using this instead:

```
<Route exact path="/r/:id" component={View} />
```